# What is this sed command doing?

Tags: sed

Can someone explain me what this `sed` command is trying to achieve?

```
sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//;s/[[:space:]]*$//
```

I understand that it is searching for whitespace characters from the beginning of the line, but I am not able to understand the part starting from `//;s/[[:space:]]*$//`

Comment: the second part is it is removing the whitespaces at the end of the line. Overall, trimming the white space characters at the beginning and at the end of the line.

Comment: is ;s part of the pattern it is trying to find or it is some keyword? I am confused just coz of this part

Comment: The `;` is to separate two commands; just like in a shell script.  It could be written `sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]//' -e 's/[[:space:]]$//'`.

Comment: Thanks @Arcege , I see that it was ; which is used to separate the two commands. It's clear to me now!

Comment: It's a **Trim**!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two `s` commands there: `sed` can take a list of commands separated by semicolons. You could put the same thing in a script file like so:

```
s/^[[:space:]]*//
s/[[:space:]]*$//
```

Also, you're parsing the `s` command wrongly: `s` isn't *search*, it is *substitute*: it takes two arguments, the string to match and the string to replace it with (`s/find/replace/`).

So, `s/^[[:space:]]*//` means

```
s                (substitute)
/^[[:space:]]*/  (leading whitespace)
//               (with an empty string)
```

and the second command `s/[[:space:]]*$//` means *substitute trailing whitespace with an empty string*.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know it's just a substitute chain. First it removes all leading whitespace via `s/^[[:space:]]//` and it moves on to apply `s/[[:space:]]$//` to remove all trailing whitespace.